# How to make javafx choiceBox fit column width

Tags: user-interface, javafx, element

I have a dialog window created dinamically. There I have TextFields and ChoiceBoxes. Text fields fits column widths and ChoiceBoxes are not. Have a look at the pic:
[image]

I need choicebox to be of the same width as textField
elements are added in this way:

```
        addingDialogPane.add(nameLabel, 0, 1);
        addingDialogPane.add(name, 1, 1);
        addingDialogPane.add(extUidLabel, 0, 2);
        addingDialogPane.add(extUid, 1, 2);
        addingDialogPane.add(is_folder, 0, 3);
        addingDialogPane.add(parentLabel, 0, 4);
        addingDialogPane.add(parent, 1, 4);
        addingDialogPane.add(confirm, 1, 5);
```

**UPD:** I've tryed to use

`parent.prefWidthProperty().add(name.getWidth());`

- no effect
  I've also tryed

`parent.prefWidth(double);`

no effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the maxWidth property of it to:

```
extUid.setMaxWidth( Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parent.prefWidthProperty().bind(extUid.widthProperty());
```